# Retrieving data from SQL server with pymssql in python is replacing 0 with False and NULL with None

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, fetchall

Following code is replacing 0 integer with False and Null with None:-

```
with open(tablename, "r") as table:
    tname = table.read().splitlines()
    sqlConnection = pymssql.connect(host_LZ,username_LZ,password_LZ,src_database)
    cursor = sqlConnection.cursor()
        for t in tname:
            sqlst = "Select * from %s" % t
            cursor.execute(sqlst)
            data = cursor.fetchall()
            print("data : ",data)
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: I dnt want it to get replaced... I want all the data as it is from table.